# Want to run the world?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have a translation assignment. The text is from a popular magazine and it says

> Want to run the world? Start by tucking in your shirt.

([Presumed source](https://schoolleadership20.com/profiles/blogs/want-to-run-the-world-start-by-tucking-in-your-shirt))

I don’t know how I should translate “run the world” Can you tell me what it exactly means in this context?

Comment: Hello Husna,  when you quote from an article, you **must** say where you are quoting from.  In this case it was quite easy to find an article that I assume you read.  It is very easy to add links to the source.  You should do this on your next question.

Answer (score 3):

In this context, the phrase *run the world* means the same as *rule the world*

This means to ‘make the rules’ for the world (and could also mean to enforce them)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will keep your advice in mind